# Number of restricted compositions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have recently learnt about restricted compositions. I am having a hard time in finding a formula for the number of restricted compositions. In other words, in how many ways we can write n as a sum of numbers from $S = {1,3,5}.$
Can you please help me?
Note that (1,2,3) is different from (1,3,2)

Comment: Are you familiar with generating functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order is important, for example, $1+1+3$ and $1+3+1$ and $3+1+1$ all get counted, then you can use the recursion
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-5}\ .$$
Here $a_n$ is the number of ways to make up $n$ in the way you want.  You will also need to find by trial and error five initial values
$$a_1=1\,,\ a_2=1\,,\ a_3=2\,,\ a_4=3\,,\ a_5=5\,.$$
There are standard methods for solving such a recursion, though in this case it will be very messy as you will need to find the roots of the polynomial
$$\lambda^5-\lambda^4-\lambda^2-1\ .$$
The recursion is explained as follows: to write $n$ as a sum of numbers from $\{1,3,5\}$ we can

- start with a $1$, then add numbers summing to $n-1$; the number of ways to do this is $a_{n-1}$; or
- start with a $3$, then add numbers summing to $n-3$; the number of ways to do this is $a_{n-3}$; or
- start with a $5$, then add numbers summing to $n-5$; the number of ways to do this is $a_{n-5}$.